# Redirect a subdomain to a subfolder in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I know it should be better in ngnix, but I have to do it in Rails (routes.rb)

My old url is:

http://**country**.example.com/whatever/whatever

New URL

http://example.com/**country**/whatever/whatever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Original Answer

With constraint (Only apply if subdomain is country.example.com)

```
constraints :subdomain => "country" do
  get "programs/:id", to: redirect { |params, req| "http://#{req.domain}/#{req.subdomain}/programs/#{params[:id]}" }
end
```

Without constraint (Will apply to any subdomain, chicken.example.com, waffles.example.com)

```
get 'programs/:id', to: redirect { |params, req| "#{req.subdomain}/programs/#{params[:id]}" }
```

### Edit to match all params

Route Globbing as specified [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments) should it. This should work:

```
constraints :subdomain => "country" do
  get "*all", to: redirect { |params, req| "http://#{req.domain}/#{req.subdomain}/#{params[:all]}" }
end
```

Bascially it's just catching all parameters in params[:all] and using that to forward them. Be sure to wrap this in a subdomain constraint though as it could catch all of your get requests, depending on where it sits in your `routes.rb` file

Comment: Yes, it works. Do you know also how to be valid for any resource?
I change this for a SEO reason. SO any Old url must be transferred. And subdomain should go away

Comment: So rather than just routing country.example.com/programs/:id you want to route anything from country.example.com/any/thing to example.com/country/any/thing ?

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Resolved. 

constraints :subdomain => /sweden|uk|finland/ do
    get "(*all)", to: redirect { |params, req| "http://#{req.domain}/#{req.subdomain}/#{params[:all]}" }
  end

Comment: Edited to include all params

Answer (score 1):

**Routes.rb**

```
constraints :subdomain => /sweden|uk|finland/ do
    get "(*all)", to: redirect { |params, req| "http://#{req.domain}/#{req.subdomain}/#{params[:all]}" }
  end
```